# Equation query in stored procedure using business rules Master Data Service

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

I would like to create business rules in master data service for amount column and the rules is column qty * column price.

Can I use business rules in MDS ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Business Rules in MDS for that but you will need to define a User Defined Script for your specific condition and/or action. The following [blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4671/business-rules-extension-in-master-data-services-2016/) on MsSqlTips shows you how to do this.